# Why would I use two controllers instead of one?

Tags: angularjs

If I have to share variables between two controllers, wouldn't it be better to just use one controller?

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

- To keep all logic in one controller - hard to maintain
- Two have two  controllers and duplicate logic- again hard to maintain
- To have two controllers and separate needed logic in service - will be
  able to reuse the logic in both contollers and remove duplication.

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse the logic"? Using prototypes?

Comment: I mean that, when you move code to a given or new service, you can use as many times you need, without copy paste in each controller. Just inject and use the service in any controller.

Answer (score 1):

you would use each applications controller for different reason,that in my opinion makes application more readable and maintainable. if you need to share something then you do it.

Answer (score 1):

The choice to use two controllers instead of one usually is based on how you decide to model the real world entities in your app. Sharing variables is not a strong enough incentive to fuse two controllers. It's preferable to maintain your controllers each one modelling its own entity and to create an Angular service for the communication needed between them.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of it as **to increase your software cohesion**.
With higher cohesion, your code is easier to maintain, reuse, test and debug.
For example, if you separate a `PersonController` into a `TeacherController` and a `StudentController` which returns teacher and student objects respectively.  When you encounter a bug in your application, eg. the Student view is not displaying grades correctly, it is much easier for you to identify which controller does the bug come from.